# Using AutoFixture to set properties on a collection as data for an Xunit theory

Tags: unit-testing, xunit.net, autofixture

I'm new to Xunit and AutoFixture, and writing a theory that looks like:

```
[Theory, AutoData]
public void Some_Unit_Test(List<MyClass> data)
{
    // Test stuff
}
```

MyClass looks like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

This causes AutoFixture to create a list of items with random values for each property. This is great, but I would like the `IsActive` property to always be true.

I could set it to true at the start of every test but I'm guessing there is a smarter way. I looked at `InlineData`, `ClassData`, `PropertyData`, even `Inject()` but nothing quite seemed to fit.

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way to do this:

```
public class Test
{
    [Theory, TestConventions]
    public void ATestMethod(List<MyClass> data)
    {
        Assert.True(data.All(x => x.IsActive));
    }
}
```

The `TestConventionsAttribute` is defined as:

```
internal class TestConventionsAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    internal TestConventionsAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture().Customize(new TestConventions()))
    {
    }

    private class TestConventions : ICustomization
    {
        public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
        {
            fixture.Customize<MyClass>(c => c.With(x => x.IsActive, true));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, Nikos. This is very useful. Just a small update, now after a while and couple of versions after there is a small change with regards to the base constructor which should be called, the one above is now obsolete. It should look something like this:

```
    private static readonly Func<IFixture> fixtureFactory = () =>
    {
        return new Fixture().Customize(new TestConventions());
    };

    public TestConventionsAttribute()
        : base(fixtureFactory)
    {
    }

    private class TestConventions : ICustomization
    {
       public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
       {
          fixture.Customize<MyClass>(c => c.With(x => x.IsActive, true));
       }
    }
```